# when i add 'Provider=..' to app.config connection string, i no longer get the bound data on my form

Tags: c#, sql

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PropellerRepairStation.Properties.Settings.PropellerRepairStationConnectionString"
         connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DAVEHAMPEL-PC\ARS;Initial Catalog=PropellerRepairStation;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If I leave the `Provider=SQLOLEDB` out of the connection string I get my bound objects on the form.

But, I get an error

> 'Provider=..' must be specified

on this line of code

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SQL, connection);
```

I have changed my approach and set a Default.ini to get the connection string from.  this actually requires many lines of code.  I have read in many posts that using a .ini file is old school and use of the app.config would be the better way to go. Any opinion on that?

I am also stuck on whether or not to use bound controls or unbound.

to get back to original question, 
if I use "Provider=SQLOLEDB;.." then use 'using System.Data.SQLClient'
or 
change to "Provider=OLEDB;.." and use 'using System.Data.OLEDB'

would there be advantages to using one over the other?
My form is for customer information and will be used to edit and add to the customer database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app.config you have defined SQLOLEDB provider which uses `System.Data.SQLClient`.
However in your code you are using the `OLEDBCommand` which uses `System.Data.OLEDB`, 
Try Changing,

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SQL, connection);
```

to

```
SQLCommand command = new SQLCommand(SQL, connection);
```